# BootCamp - Right-Click on Windows 7 running on MacBook Air

Tags: windows-7, boot-camp, right-click, macbook-air

How do you right-click on Windows 7 running on a MacBookAir?

I'm sure it used to work, but lately I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This assumes that you have the latest Boot Camp drivers installed.

> To right-click using a trackpad:
>
> Place
>   two fingers on the trackpad and click
>   the trackpad button.

Source: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=281491

Comment: Yes. After It is the double finger click on the right. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to "Control Panel".
2. Click on the phrase "System and Security".
3. Then "Boot Camp".
4. Click on the "Trackpad" tab.
5. In the "One Finger" area, enable the checkbox next to "Secondary Click".
6. Click OK.

This will let you simulate a right click by depressing the bottom-right corner of the trackpad.